# Доступ к полям класса только через его методы

Tags: ооп, классы

Принцип описанный в названии это best practices. Но возникает вопрос: в методах внутри класса помимо `get-` и `set-` методов, доступ к полям должен осуществляться посредством `get-методов` или напрямую?

Comment: Как вы себе представляете обращение внутри класса к его же полям через методы? 
А методы в свою очередь находятся не внутри класса(реализация метода)?

То что вы назвали "best practices" - просто формальность, нужна лишь для валидации данных. Чтобы неожидано для класса в его переменных не оказалось то чего там быть не может =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я придерживаюсь нескольких правил:

1. Если гет-сет методах есть хоть какая-то логика (т.е. идет не прямое
   обращение к полю), то стараюсь использовать методы доступа.
2. Если гет-сет методы могут быть перекрыты в потомках, то стараюсь
   использовать методы доступа.
3. Методы пришли из черного ящика предка, реализацию которого вы не
   знаете. Ну тут поневоле придется использовать методы.
4. Методы пришли из предка, реализацию которого может изменить кто-то другой. Лучше использовать методы.
5. Во всех остальных случаях использую поля напрямую.

---

Так как в основном стараюсь все методы доступа делать не наследуемыми (либо не виртуальными, либо помечаю их как финальные) и без логики, то в основном работаю напрямую с полями. Примерно 95% полей именно такие. Но иногда встречаются задачи, которые должны решаться именно через разные сложности. Тогда нужны методы.